# How to switch L10N in django

Tags: django, templates, internationalization, translation

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = False
```

{{ post.date_added|date:"b" }} gives "окт" in templates.
If I set USE_I18N = False then it gives oct as it should be.
Is this a bug ? How can I solve this problem ? Are there any possibilities to disable USE_I18N in template (in part of it) ?

Answer (score 2):

Django relies on strftime heavily, but : http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html
Directive   Meaning Notes
%a  Locale’s abbreviated weekday name.
%A  Locale’s full weekday name.
%b  Locale’s abbreviated month name.
%B  Locale’s full month name.

So when USE_I18N=True the month name is converted into russian because it's locale dependent.
Will write my own template tag probably :(

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 1.3 You can use `localize` and `unlocalize` filters (after loading library `l10n` i.e. doing `{% load l10n %}`).

You could try this:

```
{% load l10n %}
{{ post.date_added|unlocalize|date:"b" }}
```